# Chess PGN with time control

Tags: data-request, sports, games

I'm looking for PGN that has time control containing all FIDE classical chess games.

If that cannot be found then I would like PGN of FIDE classical games for high rated players that have time control, most PGN I've seen do not include the time. The data has to be free or for a negligible price since it's for a side project.

Comment: How many games would be enough?

Comment: @StanislavKralin I don't have a fixed number in mind because I didn't find any PGN. The more you find the better, if you find say 500 games it would be good, more better, less no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

- **43rd World Chess Olympiad 2018** *(September 23 - October 6)*: [5000+ games](https://batumi2018.fide.com/en/pgn)
- **Women's World Chess Championship Tournament 2018** *(November 2 - 23)*: [~140 games](https://ugra2018.fide.com/pgnfileen/)
- **Women's World Chess Championship Match 2018** *(May 2 - 29)*: [10 games](http://china2018.fide.com/en/component/turnuva/?task=fileview&kid=4)

---

```
[Event "WWCC 2018"]
[Site "Khanty-Mansiysk, RUS"]
[Date "2018.11.12"]
[Round "22.2"]
[White "Kosteniuk Alexandra (RUS)"]
[Black "Muzychuk Anna (UKR)"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[BlackElo "2564"]
[WhiteElo "2543"]
[ECO "B33"]

 1. e4    {[%clk 1:30:56]}   c5    {[%clk 1:30:53]}
 2. Nf3   {[%clk 1:31:20]}   e6    {[%clk 1:31:18]}
 3. d4    {[%clk 1:31:39]}   cxd4  {[%clk 1:31:41]}
 4. Nxd4  {[%clk 1:32:05]}   Nf6   {[%clk 1:32:01]}
 5. Nc3   {[%clk 1:32:15]}   Nc6   {[%clk 1:32:23]}
 6. Ndb5  {[%clk 1:32:25]}   d6    {[%clk 1:32:43]}
 7. Bf4   {[%clk 1:32:46]}   e5    {[%clk 1:33:07]}
 8. Bg5   {[%clk 1:33:12]}   a6    {[%clk 1:33:30]}
 9. Na3   {[%clk 1:33:37]}   b5    {[%clk 1:33:53]}
10. Nd5   {[%clk 1:33:40]}   Be7   {[%clk 1:34:14]}
11. Bxf6  {[%clk 1:34:03]}   Bxf6  {[%clk 1:34:35]}
12. c4    {[%clk 1:34:26]}   b4    {[%clk 1:34:46]}
13. Nc2   {[%clk 1:34:51]}   O-O   {[%clk 1:34:55]}
14. Be2   {[%clk 1:34:45]}   a5    {[%clk 1:34:48]}
15. O-O   {[%clk 1:34:52]}   Bg5   {[%clk 1:34:59]}
16. b3    {[%clk 1:35:00]}   Be6   {[%clk 1:31:28]}
17. a3    {[%clk 1:35:05]}   bxa3  {[%clk 1:25:19]}
18. Nc3   {[%clk 1:35:13]}   Qb8   {[%clk 1:12:55]}
19. Nxa3  {[%clk 1:34:33]}   Bd8   {[%clk 1:08:40]}
20. Nab5  {[%clk 1:34:21]}   Bb6   {[%clk 1:02:46]}
21. Qxd6  {[%clk 1:32:19]}   Qxd6  {[%clk 1:02:03]}
22. Nxd6  {[%clk 1:32:43]}   Nd4   {[%clk 0:54:42]}
23. Rab1  {[%clk 0:54:12]}   Rfd8  {[%clk 0:33:54]}
24. Ndb5  {[%clk 0:54:28]}   Nxe2+ {[%clk 0:34:03]}
25. Nxe2  {[%clk 0:54:53]}   a4    {[%clk 0:33:39]}
26. bxa4  {[%clk 0:44:48]}   Bxc4  {[%clk 0:30:55]}
27. Nbc3  {[%clk 0:45:08]}   Bc5   {[%clk 0:28:43]}
28. Rfd1  {[%clk 0:32:45]}   Rxd1+ {[%clk 0:26:48]}
29. Rxd1  {[%clk 0:33:11]}   Bxe2  {[%clk 0:26:42]}
30. Nxe2  {[%clk 0:33:37]}   Rxa4  {[%clk 0:26:50]}
31. Rd8+  {[%clk 0:33:44]}   1/2-1/2
```

See also [FIDE Calendar](http://www.fide.com/component/fidecalendar/?view=fidecalendar).

Comment: Is there any chance of finding FIDE championship matches with time control? Or they didn't record it back then?